# Android : Highlight some rows in the list displayed with text watcher for edittext

Tags: android, adapter, textwatcher

I have added a text watcher for my edittext and assigned a custom adapter to it with filterable interface implemented. 
SO when i type in the edittext , a list pops up with matching values. It is working good.
Now in this list i want to highlight / show with different colour some rows based on a logic. 
The logic is app specific . It is for example like if the item has a digit, shw that item in blue colour .How can i do this.

```
 adapter = new
     ContactsAutoCompleteAdapter(this,
     android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);

    editText.setAdapter(adapter);
```

i have added

```
@Override
    public void addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher) {
        super.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
        adapter.getFilter().filter(watcher.toString());  
    }
```

And the adapter is

```
private class ContactsAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
        implements Filterable {
    private ArrayList<String> resultList;

    public ContactsAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context,
            int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int index) {
        return resultList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null && semp.currentAcct.iProvider == Constants.PROVIDER_EXCHANGE) {
                    // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                    resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString()); // this will get the list of items

                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = resultList;
                    filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                    FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }
}
```

please help

Comment: show with different colour some rows based on a logic??? what logic you mean?

Comment: use spannableString to the textview of your filterable interface

Comment: Logic is app specific like if the string is a country for example.

Comment: @illegalargument , can you pls explain how to do it . ie to use spannableString

Comment: @preetha http://nocturnaldev.com/blog/2013/05/28/using-spannable-strings-in-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to override getview of my the array adapter and add the logic there.